# In Ubuntu 12.04 Screen lock feature not work

Tags: ubuntu

I am new on ubuntu. After install a screensaver from software center the screen lock feature not work.
Please help why it's happen.

Comment: not working in the sense it is not getting locked..???

Comment: no it's not locked or we can say nothing happen when Click on Lock Screen option or Ctrl + Alt + L

Comment: @ali786 please tell any possible solution.

Comment: Try this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command on terminal

```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```